# Faces Missing in Revit .dwg to Sketchup .dae into Blender

Tags: faces, collada

I am trying to do some more complex modeling for an architectural project. All of the base modeling is done in revit. I have imported it into sketchUp and exploded. All groups are importing correctly except for like 3 walls and one floor. Anyone know what could be causing this? I have looked at each piece of geometry separately in sketchUp and see no reason for this to be happening to specifically these random items. [image: Missing Face around Windows]

[image: Missing face on interior walls]

[image: Missing face and i am not sure what is happening on 2 floor]

Comment: What does this have to do with blender? The question does not seem to indicate that blender has any part in the process except for the title.

Comment: Seems a bit rude. How does this have nothing to do with Blender? These images are from a model in Blender. Seems like a reasonable inquiry.

Comment: No, I’m seriously asking. Following the trace of steps, I couldn’t tell what was imported into what first, and when the problem occurred. Maybe I should reread it ...

Comment: Ah okay. Maybe I could've added a couple commas in there. It was a Revit Model exported as .dwg imported into sketchUp, exported from SketchUp as .dae, imported .dae into Blender.

Comment: ok, that is weird. I’m going to leave this for now to someone who knows the software better, since my experience with sketch up as years old, I have no experience with rabbit. I might suggest you just try to correct it manually, since import errors are probably the worst, and double importing to convert the file into a usable format in terms of an error caused is like in a spy movie where they bounce the email all over the world to hide its origin.